# Detect if browser support file/folder upload on page load

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload

I would like to detect if browser support folder upload - **webkitGetAsEntry** on page load.

The idea is to show a proper button text:

1. 'Upload items' if browser support folder upload
2. 'Upload files' if not.

So far my solution is to check the browser name and version, but perhaps there is better way.

Has someone face this issue?

Comment: `if (DataTransferItem.webkitGetAsEntry) ...`

Comment: This occurs on upload event. I need to know before that event happen

Comment: My bad: `if (DataTransferItem.prototype.webkitGetAsEntry) ...`

Comment: Great 10x. window.DataTransferItem.prototype.webkitGetAsEntry

Comment: `window.` isn't needed; it'll work without that.